# Mustache rendering newlines as spaces

Tags: node.js, mustache

I have a simple text file that's being parsed by [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) within [`node_mailer`](https://github.com/Marak/node_mailer), e.g.:

```
This is a simple text file.

It has pretty standard new lines.
```

But the new lines are being rendered as spaces like so:

```
This is a simple text file. It has pretty standard new lines.
```

Any idea what's causing this? Is this an issue common to mustache?

Comment: If you try running mustache over the example outside of node_mailer, do get the same behavior?

Comment: I hadn't had time to update yet (busy work day), but I did run just mustache and the behavior was not duplicated. I'm guessing the problem is local to `node_mailer`, so I'm going to file an issue on GitHub.

Comment: https://github.com/Marak/node_mailer/issues/61